# Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View:

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am writing a crud admin panel, but i can't edit data.

> error Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

**Controller**

```
 public function edit($id){

        $slider = DB::table('header_sliders')->find($id);
        return   view('posts.edit',['header'=>$slider]);

       }
```

**View**

```
  <form action=""  method="POST" >
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Mətn</label>
        <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="{{$header->name}}">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Şəkil</label>
        <input type="file" name="imgName" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" value=" 
       {{$header->imgName}}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Dəyiş</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your `$slider` is `null`. Try to use `findOrFail()` instead of `find()` to catch that in your controller :

```
$slider = HeaderSlider::findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::findOrFail()

Comment: db not null there heve 2 data

Comment: can you try with `$slider = HeaderSlider::findOrFail($id);`

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
{{$header['name']}} 

{{$header['imgName']}}
```